# Timer.scheduledTimer not firing

Tags: swift, scenekit, nstimer

I am trying to calculate the time it takes a vehicle to go between two checkpoints. I have setup the following timer to achieve this.

```
func startTimer() {
    if hasStarted == true && timerStarted == false {
        print("Timing started!")
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: (#selector(activeTiming)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerStarted = true
    }
}

@objc func activeTiming() {
    print("Active timing block")
    if(hasFinished == false) {
        gameTime = gameTime + 0.001
        print("Add time succeeded")
    } else {
        gameTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The expected output would be the following:

```
Timing started!
Active timing block
Add time succeeded
Add time succeeded ... etc
```

The actual output:

```
Timing started!
```

So it would appear that the startTimer is properly being called but the timer is not firing the activeTiming block of code. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: That code works for me, but that isn't how you want to time an event because the Timer isn't that accurate.  When the event starts, record the start time `let startTime = Date()`.  When the event ends, compute `let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)`.  `elapsedTime` will be in seconds (including fractional seconds).

Comment: As @vacawama says, timers are not nearly that accurate. They only fire reliably about every 1/50 of a second, and you're trying to make a timer fire 20 times faster. He also provided a solution. (vacawama, you should post this as an answer.)

Comment: Timers run in the main thread.  I had issues activating timers from the "scenekit" thread - try DispatchQueue.main.async { Timer.schedule... }.  That got things working for me.  Also good ideas from the other comments - I used the same type of solution extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }

Comment: Pretty sure your selector needs to receive the `Timer` as a parameter. Try changing your method signature to  `@objc func activeTiming(_ sender: Timer)`. Also I don't know if this could affect, but instead of `.scheduledTimer(..., selector: (#selector(...)...)`, write the same line without enclosing `#selector()` between parenthesis.

Comment: @vacawama post that as an answer and I can mark this as solved. Your solution worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: I posted it @ColtonWagner.  I'm glad I could help and that it's working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, but that isn't how you want to time an event because the `Timer` isn't that accurate, and you are wasting a lot of computing time (read battery).

Instead, I suggest the following approach:

When the event starts, record the start time:

```
let startTime = Date()
```

When the event ends, compute the elapsed time:

```
let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
```

`elapsedTime` will be in seconds (including fractional seconds).

Answer (score 20):

I also faced a similar issue where the timer body was not getting called. I found out that the timer was getting scheduled from a background thread instead of the main thread. Wrapping it in `DispatchQueue.main.async` fixed it.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.pingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerInterval, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
        //
        Logger.shared.log(.anyCable, .debug, "timer run")
        self?.sendPing(sender: self)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Posting this code as it is what I'm using, but I’m no expert on Swift, so your mileage may vary!

```
class PerformanceTest {
    var name:           String = ""
    var tolerance:      Int64 = 0
    var lastTime:       Int64 = 0
    var thisTime:       Int64 = 0
    var delta:          Int64 = 0
    var percent:        Float = 0

    func setTolerance(vName: String, vTolerance: Int64) {
        name = vName
        tolerance = vTolerance
    }

    func reset() {
        delta = 0
        percent = Float((Float(delta) / Float(tolerance))) * 100
        //high = 0
    }

    func start() {
        lastTime = Date().toMillis()
    }

    func finish() {
        thisTime = Date().toMillis()
        let vDelta = thisTime - lastTime
        if(vDelta > delta) {
            delta = vDelta
            percent = Float((Float(delta) / Float(tolerance))) * 100
            if(delta > tolerance) {
                print("Performance Indicator: \(name) Above Tolerance" + String(format: "%3.0f", percent) + "%")
            }
        }
    }

    func display() -> String {
        //high = delta
        //print("\(vString) Tolerance: \(tolerance) Max: \(high)")
        return String(format: "%3.0f", percent) + "%  |"
    }
   }

extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
```

Usage:

```
var performanceDefenseLoop = PerformanceTest()
performanceDefenseLoop.setTolerance(vName:  "DefenseLoop", vTolerance: 150)

func timeToUpdateDefenses()
{
    performanceDefenseLoop.start()
    defesensesLoop()
    performanceDefenseLoop.finish()
    print("\(performanceDefenseLoop.Display())"
}
```

// To reset
performanceDefenseLoop.reset()

**Be sure to start timers in the main thread!**

Comment: "Be sure to start timers in the main thread" helped me. I had been starting the timer from a different thread and the timer never fired.

Comment: Please make "Be sure to start timers in the main thread" bold :P. It took me hours to figure out why my timer didn't but this helped FINALLY :D

Comment: Please move "Be sure to start timers in the main thread" to the top. Haha! Thanks.

Comment: Why do I need to start the timer on the main thread? I don't see any tutorials doing this, and when I use DispatchQueue.main.async{} to start my timers on the main thread, I sometimes get a delay in them starting, leading to them being nil longer than they should (using them to debounce, so delayed creation defeats the purpose!)

Comment: Some more info here as to why, Stock O [42319172] - as described above, they tend not to fire.  The delays might have something todo with how your using them, maybe you could share some code.

Comment: Bit too much to fit into a comment, so I shall ask a question:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74628572/timer-scheduledtimer-not-initialising-quickly-enough-if-started-on-main-thread